# finding confounded effects

Tags: combinatorial-designs

In a (3$^3$,3$^2$) design, how to find the effects confounded given the key block 
(0,0,0),(0,1,2) and (1,0,1)?

I have completed the key block.
(0,0,0),(0,1,2),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(2,1,1),(0,2,1),(2,0,2)(2,2,0),(1,2,2)
i.e., (1),bc$^2$,ac,ab,a$^2$bc,b$^2$c,a$^2$c$^2$,a$^2$b$^2$,ab$^2$c$^2$.

How to find confounded effects? I know in 2$^n$ experiments,we find the effects which have even no of letters common with key block.Does the same principle apply in this case?